# Root system terminology

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, terminology, root-systems

Let $\Phi$ be a [root system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system).  In a paper I'm writing, I need to work with subsets $\Phi' \subset \Phi$ satisfying the following two conditions:

1. For all $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \Phi'$ and $c_1,c_2 \geq 0$ such that $c_1 \lambda_1 + c_2 \lambda_2 \in \Phi$, we have $c_1 \lambda_1 + c_2 \lambda_2 \in \Phi'$.
2. For all $\lambda \in \Phi'$, we have $-\lambda \notin \Phi'$.

One example would be a choice of positive roots.

Is there a term for such subsets?  I'm not an expert in root systems or Lie theory, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: This condition seems natural, though I don't know a term; but, to clarify, are your $c$s integers, or arbitrary rationals?

Comment: A subset $C \subseteq \Phi$ is called *closed* if $\alpha, \beta \in C$ and $\alpha+\beta \in \Phi$ imply $\alpha+\beta \in C$. Not exactly the same as your conditions, but this is an important notion which has been studied a lot.

Comment: @SamHopkins, as you doubtless know, if the $c$s are integers, then (1) is equivalent to being closed.

Comment: @LSpice: They are arbitrary rationals.  I'm also not assuming that my root system is reduced, so it's possible that for a root $\lambda$ the element $\frac{1}{2}\lambda$ is also a root.

Comment: I suspect (still assuming $c$s are integers) that $\Phi'$ arises as follows: replace $\Phi$ by a closed subsystem, take a set of positive roots, and then take the complement of a further closed subsystem. But I'm not certain. (Oh, and I just saw your response. Then probably, instead of closed, take "Levi" (intersection of two opposite parabolic subsets).)

Comment: @Lspice: Yes, that does sound like what these probably are.  What's useful about them for me is that if $\Phi$ is the (relative) root system of a reductive algebraic group, then my condition ensures that the group generated by the root subgroups corresponding to elements of $\Phi'$ is a unipotent subgroup that can be decomposed as the set-theoretic product of the root subgroups associated to the non-divisible elements of $\Phi'$.  Mostly I want to make sure that there isn't a standard name for these, since otherwise I'll look like an idiot if I make one up.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455799/root-system-terminology#comment1180170_455799), if you're just looking for such a theorem, then the condition with rational $c$ can be weakened just to integral $c$, and it is Proposition 21.9(ii) of Borel.

Comment: @LSpice: Ah, that's nice!  I had included a proof since I didn't know a reference, but that shortens my paper by a page.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455799/root-system-terminology#comment1180191_455799), excellent!  If you're interested beyond the reductive case, it is discussed in Section 3.3 of [Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad - Pseudo-reductive groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316092439).  Just to have the [other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455799/root-system-terminology#comment1180186_455799) link here, as you certainly know, it's [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6).